# SQL How to group a column for a given range and join to other table for counting related rows with the first column

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, table-relationships

I need to group users column according to given year ranges. This is example year ranges (1980-1989,1990-1999,2000-2009)
 And then, I need to join to count results from another table. I created a database "user_relations" and I have created two tables to show my problem.

```
+--------------------------+
| Tables_in_user_relations |
+--------------------------+
| user_answers             |
| users                    |
+--------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And this is users table

```
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | username | birthyear |
+----+----------+-----------+
|  1 | user1    |      1980 |
|  2 | user2    |      1990 |
|  3 | user3    |      2000 |
|  4 | user4    |      1983 |
+----+----------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and this is user_answers table. I just need to count user_answers according to users which is grouped by date range.

```
+----+---------+-----------+
| id | user_id | option_id |
+----+---------+-----------+
|  1 |       1 |         1 |
|  2 |       2 |         1 |
|  3 |       3 |         2 |
|  4 |       4 |         1 |
+----+---------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

According to these tables I need to get a result something like this.

```
+------------------------------------------------
| option_id | 1980-1989 | 1990-1999 | 2000-2009 |
+------------------------------------------------
|  1        |         2 |         1 |         0 |
|  2        |         0 |         0 |         1 |
|  3        |         0 |         0 |         0 |
+------------------------------------------------
```

Note: I need to use users table firstly. I know there may be many variations to get this results. But I have to get the result in this way. This is just an example.

I hope there is someone over there who helps me. Thank you.

Comment: Is it mysql or postgresql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a case statement inside a sum for this, fairly simple:

```
select ua.option_id,
       sum(case when u.birthyear between 1980 and 1989 then 1 else 0 end) as "1980-1989",
       sum(case when u.birthyear between 1990 and 1999 then 1 else 0 end) as "1990-1999",
       sum(case when u.birthyear between 2000 and 2009 then 1 else 0 end) as "2000-2009"
from   users as u
inner  join user_answers as ua
on     ua.user_id = u.id
group  by ua.option_id
```

Comment: BTW, squire brackets is the MS SQL Server specific syntax. SQL standard and most of DBMSes (including PostgreSQL) uses double quotes.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer great answer. I want to ask one more simple question. fauxmosapien suggested pivot. Which solution has better performance for larger databases ?

Comment: I'm not sure, why don't you try both and tell us? :=)

Comment: I will go with your answer. Thank you so much again.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a PIVOT, roughly like:

```
SELECT  * from
   (SELECT option_id, 
           CASE  
                WHEN birthyear <= 2009 and birthyear >= 2000 THEN '2000-2009'
                WHEN birthyear <= 1999 and birthyear >= 1990 THEN '1990-1999'
                WHEN birthyear <= 1989 and birthyear >= 1980 THEN '1980-1989' 
--                [.... etc etc]
           END as ranges,
           1 as Responses
    FROM users u 
    INNER JOIN user_answers ua on u.id = ua.userid) source
    PIVOT (sum(responses) for ranges in ([2000-2009], [1990-1999],[1980-1989])) as Pivot
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I will check it out now.